# Azure AD Graph API: Unable to use StartsWith under Any function

Tags: azure-ad-graph-api

I would like to ask on how to apply StartsWith in Any function when querying in Azure AD Graph Explorer.

Based on the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/ad/graph/howto/azure-ad-graph-api-supported-queries-filters-and-paging-options), below is the sample when querying multi-valued properties.

```
https://graph.windows.net/contoso.com/users?$filter=signInNames/any(x:x/value eq 'joe@example.com')&api-version=1.6
```

However, the sample uses "**eq**" which means it is doing an Exact match.

Is it possible if we can perform **StartsWith** in this scenario?

I already check this [tutorial](https://www.odata.org/getting-started/basic-tutorial/#lambda) but I got the error as shown below.

**Getting all SignNames with "test"**

```
https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/users?$filter=signInNames/any(x:x.startswith(x,'test'))
```

**Error:**

```
"value": "An unknown function with name 'x.startswith' was found. This may also be a key lookup on a navigation property, which is not allowed."
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
GET https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/users?$filter=signInNames/any(c:startswith(c/value, 'test'))
```

Unfortunately, it will show an error: **value only supports equals-match. PrefixMatch is not supported**.
[image]

please use below query for signinnames in Azure Ad graph

```
https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/users?$filter=signInNames/any(c:c/value eq '***')
```

Comment: yeah i think that's the case. Thanks!